# Does angularJS need configuration on remote server?

Tags: angularjs, remote-server

I tried to deploy an angularJS app to the remote server but I still see the default apache page on visiting the url. Please what do I need to do to make the view work as I can view the app on my localhost.

Comment: Did you set the document root correctly?

Comment: Can you show us what you installed exactly? Maybe something went wrong while uploading the app.

Comment: If you mean my deployment path on the remote server, I set it correctly. I have other apps running on the server.

Comment: @cdslijngard kindly see the files <img src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/5044/7X8xgz.png " width="167" height="201">

Answer (score 0):

I had this once. You'll need to update the root from the Apache server to point to your Angular application. For example: if your Apache is running on an Ubuntu server, open your apache2.conf file and change the root location.

Comment: I changed /var/www/ to /var/www/html and still no success.